# separate Doctest function that i can run on all my scripts

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that i can call within my scripts that'll automatically run doctest so I don't have to type it out each time. (I'm lazy I know). however each time I try to call the saved function within my code itll give me a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cameron/Documents/Bubble sort .py", line 25, in <module>
    import doctest1.doctester
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'doctest1'
```

Here is a copy of the code that I wrote.

```
def doctester():

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import doctest
        doctest.testmod()
```

and here is how I am trying to call it.

```
def bubble_sort(L):
    """

    >>> L = [7, 3, 5, 2]
    >>> bubble_sort(L)
    >>> L
    [2, 3, 5, 7]
    """
    end = len(L) - 1

    while end != 0:
         for i in range (end):
             if L[i] > L[i + 1]:
                 L[i], L[i +1] = L[i + 1], L[i] 

         end = end - 1


import doctest1.doctester
```

Comment: Where do you think `doctest1` is defined?

Comment: doctest1 is the name of the file containing the function doctester. Sorry I didn't say that

Comment: Why should Python recognize it as a module?